# How to strip and split in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to perform a split by new line and also do a strip of whitespaces in a single line ?
this is how my df looks like originally

```
 df["Source"]
0       test1   \n test2   
1       test1   \n test2   
2       test1   \ntest2    
Name: Source, dtype: object
```

I used to do a split based on new line and create a list with the below code

```
Data = (df["Source"].str.split("\n").to_list())

Data
    [['test1   ', ' test2   '], ['   test1   ', ' test2   '], ['  test1   ', 'test2    ']]
```

I want to further improve this and remove any leading or trailing white spaces and i am not sure how to use the split and strip in a single line

```
df['Port']
0    443\n8080\n161
1                25
2               169
3                25
4          2014\n58
Name: Port, dtype: object
```

when i try to split it based on the new line , it fills in nan values for the ones that does not have \n

```
df['Port'].str.split("\n").to_list()
[['443', '8080', '161'], nan, nan, nan, ['2014', '58']]
```

the same works perfectly for other columns

```
df['Source Hostname']
0    test1\ntest2\ntest3
1                  test5
2         test7\ntest8\n
3                  test1
4           test2\ntest4
Name: Source Hostname, dtype: object
df["Source Hostname"].str.split('\n').apply(lambda z: [e.strip() for e in z]).tolist()
[['test1', 'test2', 'test3'], ['test5'], ['test7', 'test8', ''], ['test1'], ['test2', 'test4']]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
df['Source'].str.split('\n').apply(lambda x: [e.strip() for e in x]).tolist()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate.. that worked perfect. Is there a way to include a column name that has a space in between for instance - source hostname instead of source

Comment: Hey mate, if you use [ ] , you can put any column name in it. I've just updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks. that worked too :). I am getting some issues with another column that has Port numbers in it, and it is giving an error  " TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable" I have added the df for Ports in my original post. Also is there a way to split based on new line only if there is a new line. for some reason all this is not working for Ports, the way it works for the other columns

Comment: Thanks mate.. worked just as you said.. do you have some kind of a cheatsheet or something ;) . Relly helpful of you . Thanks a mil

Comment: No worries mate. Glad it helped!

Comment: If you have any NaN values in your series and you get the error 'float' object has no attribute 'split', try `.map` with na_action='ignore', e.g.: `df['Source'].str.split('\n').map(lambda x: [e.strip() for e in x], na_action='ignore').tolist()`

Answer (score 7):

Use [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) for remove traling whitespaces and then `split` by regex `\s*\n\s*` for one or zero whitespaces before and after `\n`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Source':['test1   \n test2   ',
                             '    test1   \n test2   ',
                             '    test1   \ntest2   ']})
print (df)
                    Source
0      test1   \n test2   
1      test1   \n test2   
2       test1   \ntest2

Data = (df["Source"].str.strip().str.split("\s*\n\s*").to_list())
print (Data)
[['test1', 'test2'], ['test1', 'test2'], ['test1', 'test2']]
```

Or if possible split by arbitrary whitespace (it means spaces or `\n` here):

```
Data = (df["Source"].str.strip().str.split().to_list())
print (Data)
[['test1', 'test2'], ['test1', 'test2'], ['test1', 'test2']]
```